# How to change done button title in NohanaImagePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepicker

How can we change the title of the done button in `NohanaImagePicker`?

Comment: Instead of giving downvote, please suggest the new contributor that what should be done. @Vrinda, Can you please share more detail that what you tried to do that? What is nohana?

Comment: Welcome, Vrinda. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) out before asking questions on Stackoverflow.
Good luck with finding your answers!

Comment: sometimes, it might be easier to drop a question in the library's repo or check their readme to see where the contributors are listening to.  Is this the one? https://github.com/nohana/NohanaImagePicker

Comment: @VrindaMittal have you got your answer?

Answer (score 0):

[NohanaImagePicker](https://github.com/nohana/NohanaImagePicker) is a library to pick multiple images or videos from photos. It's used system `done` button on the navigation bar. It has no reference in the `ViewController` class.

If you really want to change the bone button text then you need to manually add the library in your project.

Then open `NohanaImagePicker.storyboard` from the library directory.
You can see the `done` button on the navigation bar. Probably in two ViewController. In this way, you can change the done button text.